# Convergence of sequence of the form $a_n = \frac{1}{n^\alpha} + \cdots + \frac{1}{(2n)^\alpha}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Determine the convergence or divergence of the following sequences:

(a) $a_n= 1/n^2 + 1/(n + 1)^2 + \cdots + 1/(2n)^2$,

(b) $b_n= 1/n + 1/(n+1) + \cdots + 1/(2n)$,

(c) $c_n = 1/\sqrt n + 1/\sqrt{n+1} + \cdots + 1/\sqrt{2n}$.

I want to say they all will converge to zero, but I feel that may be too simple and I am missing something... need help, thank you!

Comment: My bad, I know the last term will go to zero, so then it must be that those sequences will converge?

Comment: Perhaps edit the question to show your process, rather than use the comments

Comment: The first is not hard, the limit is $0$. The second is less easy, the limit exists but is not $0$ . The third diverges, proof easy.

Comment: so I get the first one is bounded above by 2 but what does it converge to? and why is it that the third one diverges?

Comment: For $(c)$ try to use the fact that there are $n$ terms while which terms are more or less $\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$.

Comment: The first sum is $\le \frac{n+1}{n^2}$. The third has  $n+1$ terms all $\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}$, so is $\ge \frac{n+1}{\sqrt{2n}}$, which blows up.

Comment: the second one converges to the natural logarithm of 2. Look up "Euler's constant."

Comment: so the best way is to use the comparison test?

Comment: You have terms approaching $0$, but at the same time the _number_ of terms is increading, offsetting the decrease in the sizes of terms.

Comment: Yup I understand that, so why is it that the later terms for c_n aren't going to zero?

Comment: check my answer. you will find its reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$b_n= \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n+1} + . . . \frac{1}{2n}= \frac{1}{n}(1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}}+\frac{1}{1+\frac{2}{n}}+...)=\int^{1}_{0}\frac{1}{1+x}=\ln(1+x)\vert‎^{1}_{0}=\ln2$

$a_n=\frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{1}{(n + 1)^2} + . . . + \frac{1}{(2n)^2}=\frac{1}{n}(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{(1 + \frac{1}{n})^2}+...)=\int^{1}_{0} \frac{1}{(1+x)^2}=\frac{-1}{(1+x)}\vert‎^{1}_{0}$

$c_n \geq n\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}\rightarrow \infty‎‎$

Comment: This was very helpful! Thank you.